# Displaying diagonal fractions in HTML

Tags: html, css

I had followed many of the posts in StackOverflow, but they talk about stacked fractions.
I was working on displaying diagonal fractions like this:
[image]
Here is my code :

```css
* {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.numerator {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.denominator {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<span class="container"><span class="numerator">3</span><span class="denominator">5</span></span><br><br>
<span class="container"><span class="numerator">17</span><span class="denominator">4113</span></span>
```

Note: I have added borders just for clarity.

But, I cannot figure out how to add that **slash** in between. Please help.

Comment: http://unicodefractions.com/

Comment: I know about these, but these are a few. I want a solution which will work with any text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a pseudo element like below. You can also simplify your grid code a lot:

```css
* {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.container {
  display: inline-grid;
}

.denominator {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.numerator {
  position: relative;
}

.numerator:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  /* Give top and bottom the same value*/
  top: 50%;
  bottom: -50%;
  width: 3px;
  background: black;
  transform: rotate(45deg); /* Adjust this like you want */
}


/* Irrelevant styles */
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.numerator {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.denominator {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<span class="container"><span class="numerator">3</span><span class="denominator">5</span></span><br><br>
<span class="container"><span class="numerator">17</span><span class="denominator">4113</span></span>
```

Answer (score 5):

One simple way is to just use the subscript tag, and the superscript tag.

```
<p>This text contains <sup>23</sup>/<sub>24</sub> of a number</p>
```

This text contains <sup>23</sup>/<sub>24</sub> of a number

Comment: There is a "Fraction Slash" Unicode character:  ⁄` (U+2044). Might look a bit better than the regular slash.

Answer (score 1):

here's another approach using rotate transformation.

```css
.fraction {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  transform: rotate(16deg);
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.denominator,
.numerator {
  transform: rotate(-16deg);
}

.denominator {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.divide {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="fraction">
    <span class="numerator">3</span>
    <span class="divide">/</span>
    <span class="denominator">5</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This trick works, but only if the numerator and denominator consist of a single digit. Whenever there are more than one digit, the fraction goes out of bounds.

Comment: In case of more than one digit, `css` will have to be tweaked to account for the digits

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a nearly result with [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align):

```css
* {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.numerator::after {
  content: '/';
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
}

.numerator {
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

.denominator {
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span class="numerator">323</span>
  <span class="denominator">5</span>
</span>

<br><br>
<span class="container">
  <span class="numerator">17</span>
  <span class="denominator">4113</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also make a mix and  look at `vertical-align`, pseudo element (or even `background` to draw a line)  and dedicated html tags like `<sup>` & `<sub>`.

here is a possible mix

```css
span,
sup,
b {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0.2em 0 0
}
.PI {font-weight:bold;font-family:cursive}

b.bot:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 1.5em;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -.3em;
  border: solid 1px;
  transform: rotate(30deg)
}

.bot {
  padding: 0 0.2em;
  ;
  vertical-align: -.5em;
  position: relative
}
.disclaimer {color:tomato;}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="PI">
  (16<b class="bot">9</b>)<sup>2</sup> = &pi;</span> <sub class="disclaimer">3,160493827160494 was about 1800 Yrs BC !</sub>
  <p>
```